# Error on my namespace and how do i fix it RDL report?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I am having this error and have installed RDLC report to my Visual Studio and have a controller that exports RDLC report to Excel. Now when I try to run view.cshtml and get this error

> "the tag RDLReportViewer does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:DSoft.RDL;assembly=RDLCPrinter. Line 11 Position 10".

```
//Window.xaml

<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        xmlns:RDLC="clr-namespace:DSoft.RDLC;assembly=RDLCPrinter"
        x:Class="RDLCDemo.MainWindow" 
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="RDLC WPF UserControl Demo" Height="800" Width="1024">
    <Grid>

        <RDLC:RDLCReportViewer x:Name="ReportViewer" Margin="10" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have RDLC DDL present in you dependency also check name also check RDLC in wpf

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rdlc-report-using-wpf-and-c-sharp/